# How can I perform mongodb search

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, react-native

I have a list of documents as follows

```
[{"userId": "1", "text": "National security is of utmost importance"}, {"userId": "2", "text": "We must ensure a strong defense while upholding civil liberties and protecting human rights"}]
```

how can I search the documents with an array such as ["national", "strong defence"] and get documents with any of the tags with mongodb nodejs aggregation

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `fuzzy` field to perform the search, you can read about it here [Text Search - MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/text/)

Your query would look something like this,

```
{
  $search: {
    "text": {
      "query": arrayToSearchFor,
      "path": "text",
      "fuzzy": <options>,
    }
  }
}
```

The `fuzzy` field takes three options, `maxEdits`, `prefixLength`, `maxExpansions`. They are all optional and you can read more about them [here.](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/text/#fields)